# How can the testers access to the internal test app on Google play?

Tags: testing, google-play, google-play-internal-testing

I’m trying to distribute my test app to 2internal testers. Yesterday I completed upload the App Bundle of my app and now my google console is something like this.[image]

I thought once I upload the app bundle, I could get opt-in URL and I can share the link to testers, or since I registered testers’ email address as a list, they get an email with opt-in URL. I’ve uploaded the bundle about 9 hours ago, but I still cannot see the opt-in URL and not sure where my testers can access the internal test app. Could someone teach me what I need to do to get the opt-in URL and what I’m doing wrong here?

Also, I realized that there are checklist on the dashboard and currently I only got app releases and pricing & distribution checked. Do I need to make other things checked (I mean App content, rating, and store listing) in order to get my opt-in URL for testing??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to start rollout for the internal test. Then your app will be reviewed and you will get an opt-in URL.

The opt-in link only shows when an app is "Published." Apps in "Draft" or "Pending publication" won't show the opt-in link.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213